# "Permission denied" to install Eclipse Color Theme plugin in Juno

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse-plugin

I run Ubuntu 12.04 and I managed to install Eclipse Juno and its accompanying SDK.  I placed the folders into the /opt directory.

I wanted to install the popular Eclipse plugin, Eclipse Color Theme, but I encountered this error message. https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8ywd.png

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have write permission to /opt. You can use the following command to give yourself ownership.

```
sudo chown -R USER_NAME /opt/ECLIPSE_DIRECTORY
```

Of course, you will have to replace USER_NAME with your username or group and ECLIPSE_DIRECTORY with the root directory for eclipse. If you have /opt/eclipse and your name was "Jack", the command would be